# seqformat creates sequences with NA values in R

Tags: r, regression, sequence, traminer

I'm using `seqformat` in R to analyze the sequence of events.

I have this data, for example, for practice where I have a huge dataset, but I'm using it to understand the function format:

```
   
 Location_Id     Event       Start_day    End_day   temp    year         
     1         Sever snow       6              12     4     2014          
     1         Medium snow      15             21     6     2016          
     2         Sever snow       7              8      3     2013
```

I used this command:

```
sts.data <- seqformat(df, from="SPELL", to="STS", id="Event", begin="Start_day", end="End_day", status="temp",limit=3)
```

When I run the command, I get this message

```
    [!!] max of 'end' column > limit! Sequences truncated at limit= 3     [>]

converting SPELL data into 2 STS sequences (internal format)
```

The output with NA values is as below

```
                 a1    a2    a3
Sever snow       NA    NA    NA       
Medium snow      NA    NA    NA
```

I'm not sure if the `end` parameter needs to be greater than the `begin` parameter among all events or this is not the problem.

Any thoughts about why I can't have this sequence of events created successfully, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `limit` argument sets the maximum length of the sequences. In your data the first valid information is at day 6 and, therefore, the first three positions (days) are NAs.

The latest valid information is on day 21. To avoid truncation of the sequences, set `limit=21` or larger. Note also that the function may produce unexpected results when ids are not contiguous. Since you are using `Event` as id, I sort the rows of `df` by `Event` to make ids contiguous.

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text = "
Location_Id     Event       Start_day    End_day   temp    year
     1         Sever.snow       6              12     4     2014          
     1         Medium.snow      15             21     6     2016          
     2         Sever.snow       7              8      3     2013
                 ")
## Event used as id: sort to make identical ids contiguous
df <- df[order(df[,"Event"]),]
sts.data <- seqformat(df, from="SPELL", to="STS", id="Event",
        begin="Start_day", end="End_day", status="temp",limit=21)
sts.data
#             a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 a10 a11 a12 a13 a14 a15 a16 a17 a18 a19 a20 a21
# Medium.snow NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   6   6   6   6   6   6   6
# Sever.snow  NA NA NA NA NA  4  3  3  4   4   4   4  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```